# How do I create a persistent volume claim with ReadWriteMany in GKE - Windows Node pool?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nfs, persistent-storage, windows-container

I'm working on a project where we're planning to migrate existing Dot net applications to GKE (Windows nodes). The problem is, in the existing state, different applications connect a windows shared drive(external) and perform simultaneous read/write operations on files. Now we want to achieve the same thing on GKE/GCP where multiple pods interact with a file system in readWrite mode in parallel.
We've explored the below options:

1. GCE PD (ReadWriteMany is not supported) https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes
2. NFS File Storage (Windows containers not supported) https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-windows/20190103-windows-node-support.md
3. Google Filestore (Internally uses NFS & may not be supported by Windows)

I've verified multiple sources but unable to figure what solution fits in our requirement. Request for any help for the above mentioned scenario.

Comment: Filestore likely will not work. You might want to try something like Rook using flexvolumes which may be supported, though it's not clear. More recent versions of Rook use csi drivers, which will not work

Comment: Can you please provide any reference implementation link. I tried looking for it but couldn't get any help for the windows containers.

Comment: I don't actually know if it will work, rook does not.mwntuon it will work. The link you provided mentions flexvolumee possibly working